# Проблема с условием if

Tags: javascript

```
// Выбираем случайное слово из массива
var words = ["программа", "процессор", "прекрасный", "робот"];
var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
// Неугаданные буквы
var remainingLetters = word.length;
// Попытки
var remainingAttempt = 3;
// Создаем массив ответов и заполняем его
var answerArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    answerArray[i] = "_";
};

// Основной цикл программы
while (remainingLetters > 0 && remainingAttempt > 0) {
    alert('Текущее слово : ' + answerArray.join(" "));
    var guess = prompt("Угадайте букву или нажмите отмена для выхода из игры.");
    guess = guess.toLowerCase(); 
    console.log(guess);
    if (guess === null) {
        break;
    } else if (guess.length !== 1) {
        alert("Пожайлуста, введите только одну букву.");
    } else {
        for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
            if (word[j] === guess) {
                if (answerArray[j] === '_') {
                    answerArray[j] = guess;
                    remainingLetters--;
                    alert("Вы угадали букву!");
                } else {
                    alert("Вы уже угадали эту букву!");
                }
            } else {
                remainingAttempt--;
                alert('Попыток осталось ' + remainingAttempt);
                break;
            } 
        }
    }
}


alert('Результат : ' + answerArray.join(" "));
alert("Конец игры! Было загадано слово " + word);
```

Не могу понять, почему в примере условие `if (word[j] === guess)` становится равным `false`, хотя буква вводится та, которая есть в слове и переходит к своему `else`. Если убрать `else`, то все работает как надо. Помогите разобраться.

Comment: А если `===` заменить на `==` ?

Comment: @alexx Попробуйте так word[j] === guess[0]

Comment: неее, какой тут ===, тут все проще, ты когда по буквам шагаешь, у тебя цикл проходит по всему слову каждую попытку и от этого, если даже угадал одну букву остальные false будут

Comment: @arkadij_ok, стоит написать ответ

Comment: вообще на данный момент рассчитывается, что буквы будут угадываться по порядку, то есть нельзя угадать последнюю букву не угадав все буквы перед ней. стоит полностью пересмотреть логику проверки

Answer (score 2):

Тут все дело в том, что у тебя цикл for проходит по всему слову и если ты угадываешь букву он всеравно проверяет остальные, где и выдает false

Answer (score -2):

Оператор `==` сравнивает на равенство)) c преобразованием типов, а вот `===` сравнивает на идентичность.
[Отличия == и === в JavaScript](https://habrahabr.ru/post/138272/)

Comment: в данном случае это не имеет значения

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.